# Convert columns to sub-field by grouping

Tags: r, logic

I would like to convert the following data from

```
        day fox hare wolf
1    Monday   4   20    2
2   Tuesday   4   25    1
3 Wednesday   4   30    3
```

To

```
        day attribute
1    Monday   fox=4,hare=20,wolf=2
2   Tuesday   fox=4,hare=25,wolf=1
3 Wednesday   fox=4,hare=30,wolf=3
```

I tried to use tidyr, but it doesn't seem to go anywhere....

Anyone, please advise.

[Data manipulation reference](https://cyberhelp.sesync.org/data-manipulation-in-R-lesson/2016/07/26/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible approaches:

**1)** With [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse) packages:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  gather(k, v, 2:4) %>% 
  unite('attribute', k, v, sep = '=') %>% 
  group_by(day) %>% 
  summarise(attribute = paste0(attribute, collapse = ','))
```

**2)** With the [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) package:

```
library(data.table)

melt(setDT(df), id = 1)[, attribute := paste(variable, value, sep = '=')
                        ][, .(attribute = paste0(attribute, collapse = ',')), by = day]
```

which both give (`tidyverse` output shown):

> ```
> # A tibble: 3 x 2
>   day       attribute           
>   <chr>     <chr>               
> 1 Monday    fox=4,hare=20,wolf=2
> 2 Tuesday   fox=4,hare=25,wolf=1
> 3 Wednesday fox=4,hare=30,wolf=3
> ```